# Old-style print pattern

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, patterns

How do I easily replicate this pattern digitally (Photoshop preffered)? It's on an endpaper from an accounting book from ~1920s.

[image]

Comment: You might have some luck browsing the library of http://www.textures.com.

Comment: There are tutorials for creating custom seamless patterns on the internet - like this one http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2015/01/how-to-create-a-seamless-pattern-tile-in-photoshop.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have the physical paper, take a photo. The task is not trivial. The camera, lens, lights and possible cleanup edits must be pro quality. But it's still the easiest way to get a plausible result.

Why: The pattern has no periodicity in the visible area. To create this artificially one must be able to program an algorithm that fills the plane with a non-repeating pattern that resembles the result or he must have it as a photo. Finally he must find the effects for the exact look. As well one can take a photo of the real thing.

*Some speculation:* If one puts some grease drops (more solid than oil) between two straight and smooth planar surfaces and pulls the planes apart, he can get something that resembles your pattern. Maybe a glass and a flexible other plane to be able to get them apart easily.